# sql 2008 r2 countdown timer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a column in my table called TimeLeft of type datetime, days:hours:minutes (ie: 1:12:30 for 1 day 12h 30 mins)

What I need to do is pull this data via an .net page page and I need it to countdown in realtime from the time it was entered until 0.

Also what datatype should I use if I want to represent just dd:hh:mm in a column (ie: 07:00:00 would be 7 days)

How to go about doing just that?

Comment: use the `DATETIME` datatype. The way the data is stored doesn't have any relevance with the way it is presented in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not save the current countdown time, but the endtime for the countdown. Then calculate the time left before the endtime. This will give you the countdowntime.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. What data type would I need to store 07:00:00 (days:hours:minutes)? in a sql column?

Comment: You should just store the enddate as a datetime, and make the calculation in you program or query. When storing you can add the days, hours, minutes to the current time and save it in the database.

Comment: You see I do not have the start and endtimes. I just have 07:00:00 which is the TotalTime, then 05:00:00 which is ElapsedTime, and TiMeLeft would be 07:00:00 - 05:00:00 = 02:00:00 (2 days). So how to store the 07:00:00, I know it can be stored as varchar but then what CONVERT function can I use to make it dd:hh:mm and then use DATEDIFF?